# PHP session not being unset on new server

Tags: php, apache, session, ubuntu-14.04

I recently moved to a new DigitalOcean VPS server, and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Apache. This is the first time I set up my own server. I imported my website into the new server. Everything seems to be working but the logout script where I basically unset and destroy the session. For some reason, this doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Here's the code for my logout script

```
<?PHP
session_start();
session_unset();
session_write_close();
session_destroy();

session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
$_SESSION['logged_out'] = 1;
header ("Location:index.php");
?>
```

When the page is redirected, the user is still logged in and the session cookie is still set.

Comment: Because you set the session again after you destroyed it....

Comment: I used to do that before too. And my script checks for the user variables, in order to determine wether the user is logged in or not, which should be unset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else's future reference, I solved the problem. The URL for the login script was http://website.com (without the www) and the rest of my site used http://www.website.com (with the www).

Answer (score 1):

I remember having the same problem as you.
Try to delete your SESSION using : `unset($_SESSION['session_you_need_to_destroy']);`

I guess if you destroy only one session, you member will be log off.

Hope it's work for you :)

Comment: I've tried unsetting the entire $_SESSION (unset($_SESSION)), which you shouldn't do, but it's still set

Comment: Yes I know ! I had the same strange problem. It wasn't working with the entire SESSION but it was with specific value. I still don't know why but it was working for me :)

Comment: I've tried this as well. It made no difference, when I dumped the variables in the logout script, only the logged_out variable is present. After the redirect, all of the previous variables become available again